# Controlling Buttons From New Thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I am trying to change the background color of multiple buttons on a form from a separate thread. I think the problem that I am having is related to my use of a dictionary to access the buttons. Here is my code:

```
Public Shared numsToDisplay As New List(Of Integer)
Public Shared buttons As New Dictionary(Of String, Control)


Private disThread As Thread

Public Sub DisplayNums()
    disThread = New Thread(AddressOf Display)
    disThread.IsBackground = True
    disThread.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Display()
    buttons.Add("Button1", Button1)
    buttons.Add("Button2", Button2)
    buttons.Add("Button3", Button3)
    buttons.Add("Button4", Button4)
    buttons.Add("Button5", Button5)
    buttons.Add("Button6", Button6)
    buttons.Add("Button7", Button7)
    buttons.Add("Button8", Button8)
    buttons.Add("Button9", Button9)
    buttons.Add("Button10", Button10)
    buttons.Add("Button11", Button11)
    buttons.Add("Button12", Button12)
    buttons.Add("Button13", Button13)
    buttons.Add("Button14", Button14)
    buttons.Add("Button15", Button15)
    buttons.Add("Button16", Button16)
    buttons.Add("Button17", Button17)
    buttons.Add("Button18", Button18)
    buttons.Add("Button19", Button19)
    buttons.Add("Button20", Button20)
    buttons.Add("Button21", Button21)
    buttons.Add("Button22", Button22)
    buttons.Add("Button23", Button23)
    buttons.Add("Button24", Button24)
    buttons.Add("Button25", Button25)
    buttons.Add("Button26", Button26)
    buttons.Add("Button27", Button27)
    buttons.Add("Button28", Button28)
    buttons.Add("Button29", Button29)
    buttons.Add("Button30", Button30)
    buttons.Add("Button31", Button31)
    buttons.Add("Button32", Button32)
    buttons.Add("Button33", Button33)
    buttons.Add("Button34", Button34)
    buttons.Add("Button35", Button35)
    buttons.Add("Button36", Button36)
    buttons.Add("Button37", Button37)
    buttons.Add("Button38", Button38)
    buttons.Add("Button39", Button39)
    buttons.Add("Button40", Button40)
    buttons.Add("Button41", Button41)
    buttons.Add("Button42", Button42)
    buttons.Add("Button43", Button43)
    buttons.Add("Button44", Button44)
    buttons.Add("Button45", Button45)
    buttons.Add("Button46", Button46)
    buttons.Add("Button47", Button47)
    buttons.Add("Button48", Button48)
    buttons.Add("Button49", Button49)
    buttons.Add("Button50", Button50)
    buttons.Add("Button51", Button51)
    buttons.Add("Button52", Button52)
    buttons.Add("Button53", Button53)
    buttons.Add("Button54", Button54)
    buttons.Add("Button55", Button55)
    buttons.Add("Button56", Button56)
    buttons.Add("Button57", Button57)
    buttons.Add("Button58", Button58)
    buttons.Add("Button59", Button59)
    buttons.Add("Button60", Button60)
    buttons.Add("Button61", Button61)
    buttons.Add("Button62", Button62)
    buttons.Add("Button63", Button63)
    buttons.Add("Button64", Button64)
    buttons.Add("Button65", Button65)
    buttons.Add("Button66", Button66)
    buttons.Add("Button67", Button67)
    buttons.Add("Button68", Button68)
    buttons.Add("Button69", Button69)
    buttons.Add("Button70", Button70)
    buttons.Add("Button71", Button71)
    buttons.Add("Button72", Button72)
    buttons.Add("Button73", Button73)
    buttons.Add("Button74", Button74)
    buttons.Add("Button75", Button75)
    buttons.Add("Button76", Button76)
    buttons.Add("Button77", Button77)
    buttons.Add("Button78", Button78)
    buttons.Add("Button79", Button79)
    buttons.Add("Button80", Button80)
    For Each num In numsToDisplay
        SetColor(num)
    Next
End Sub

Delegate Sub SetColorCallback([num] As Integer)

Private Sub SetColor(ByVal [num] As Integer)

    ' InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
    ' calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
    ' If these threads are different, it returns true.
    If buttons("Button" & [num]).InvokeRequired Then
        Debug.Print("Invoking")
        Dim d As New SetColorCallback(AddressOf SetColor)
        Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {[num]})
    Else
        buttons("Button" & [num]).BackColor = Color.Red
    End If
End Sub
```

DisplayNums() is called by a separate form. The invoke never happens even though it should. I am also not getting any errors caused by attempting to access forms through incorrect threads.

Comment: It looks like `numsToDisplay` isn't used and is therefore empty.  Note that if you call `SetColor(1)` in `Display()`, it will change the color of `Button1`.

Comment: @JimHewitt Yes, Sorry. the numsToDisplay variable is filled by a separate form before the call to DisplayNums().

Comment: @JimHewitt Yes, But I can't tell why the InvokeRequired is returning false instead of true. Or why I don't get the usual exceptions what attempting to make unsafe thread calls.